# Registration Form in Node js using Express and Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to node js, i am following Traversy media's node series which is almost three years old.
I created a registration form, but the issue is that when i submit the form, the page instead of redirecting to the login page prompt with some frontend error ([error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTVCb.png)). I could not find any solution to this. So please if someone help me.

The relevant screenshots are posted.

Thankyou.

**user.js (Route)**

```
const express = require('express')
const router =  express.Router()
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

//User Model
let User = require('../models/user')

// Express Validator Middleware
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

//Register Form
router.get('/register', (req, res)=> {
    res.render('register')
})

//Register Process
router.post('/register', [
    check('name').notEmpty().withMessage('Name is required'),
    check('email').notEmpty().withMessage('Email is required'),
    check('email').isEmail().withMessage('Email is not valid'),
    check('username').notEmpty().withMessage('Username is required'),
    check('password').isEmpty().withMessage('Password is required'),
    check('password2').matches('password').withMessage('Passwords do not match')
], (req, res)=> {
    let user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        password2: req.body.password2
    })

    //Get Errors
    const errors = validationResult(req)

    if(errors)
    {
        res.render('register', {
            errors: errors
        })
    }
    else
    {
        user.name = req.body.name;
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.password = req.body.password;

        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=> {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash)=> {
                if(err)
                {
                    return
                }
                user.password = hash
                user.save((err)=> {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        return
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and can log in!')
                        res.redirect('/users/login')
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }
})

router.get('/login', (req, res)=> {
    res.render('login')
})

module.exports = router;
```

*** user model ***

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//User Schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        reqiured: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        reqiured: true
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        reqiured: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        reqiured: true
    }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

*** registration form ***

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Register
    form(action="/users/register", method="post")
        #form-group
            label Name:
            input.form-control(name="name" type="text")
        #form-group
            label Email:
            input.form-control(name="email" type="text")
        #form-group
            label Username:
            input.form-control(name="username" type="text")
        #form-group
            label Password:
            input.form-control(name="password" type="password")
        #form-group
            label Confirm:
            input.form-control(name="password2" type="password")
        br
        input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

Comment: What is the value of `errors` in your controller for POST route `/register` when you submit the form?

Comment: Can I give you and advice? Maybe you want to use sentry.io to get clearer error messages when you make requests to your API. In sentry.io webpage, it has 
 instructions on how to make it work. When you make an API call, if the server gets an error, it will return a lot of detail about the error if youy're using sentry correctly, and this way you might be able to know exactly what the problem is, if it is in the backend.

It is not very easy to know the error the way you posted, But I can make a small API working with the code you wrote, I will try it now.

Comment: @mgarcia the log result of the error is this:

`Result {
  formatter: [Function: formatter],
  errors: [
    {
      value: 'user12345',
      msg: 'Password is required',
      param: 'password',
      location: 'body'
    },
    {
      value: 'user12345',
      msg: 'Passwords do not match',
      param: 'password2',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @PedroHenriqueBufulindeAlme i am gonna check sentry.io . Thanks

Comment: What is that registration form? What are you using to make it? I'm testing the code you made, and only at adding users to the database, there is no problem. I did it with `express.json()`and it works just fine. The error is not in saving in the database, as far I've tested. If possible, link your github project, please. I need more details

Comment: @PedroHenriqueBufulindeAlme This is the project : https://github.com/Umayr7/Article-App

Comment: It seems that you are filling the form without including a password (hence the error you get). How are you rendering those errors in your `register` template?

Comment: @mgarcia using express validator

Comment: So when i comment out express-validator and let errors variable empty(which previously had express-validator called in it). Then my registration form is submitting fine. But now its not checking validations (Like i can submit an empty form too). So, now what ?